# Crosstab data in SQL results

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, crosstab

I got this kind of data on my db.

[image]

I need to show a result like this:

[image]

Using crystal reports this is doable. Hope someone can help me write a query for this.

Comment: Will there only be 3 days of data, or could the number of days be variable?

Comment: It is a variable only showed 3 days as a sample.

Comment: You're looking for something called a pivot query, but it will probably have to be dynamic in your case.

Comment: throw sample data.no image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not something that you would normally do using SQL, much better to implement in the application. But if you wanted to do it then you could do something like this:

```
SELECT Item,
    [01/01/2016 - Unique Emp ID] = Count(Distinct iif([Date] = Convert(date, '01-01-2016', [Emp ID], NULL)),
    [01/01/2016 - Sum Qty] = Sum(iif([Date] = Convert(date, '01-01'2016', [Qty Bought], NULL)),
    [02/01/2016 - Unique Emp ID] = Count(Distinct iif([Date] = Convert(date, '02-01-2016', [Emp ID], NULL)),
    ...
  FROM MyTable;
```

The downside here is that the column headings are fixed. That's why you should do this in the application.